# Creating a looping background task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'd like to create an AsyncTask that sits in the background and calls a web service every X seconds.

```
    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        if (params.length > 0) {
            int intUserId = params[0];

            if (intUserId != -1) {
                boolean blnRunning = true;
                while (blnRunning) {
                    // perform query

                    try {
                        this.wait(15000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        blnRunning = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean blnLaunchStoreFavorites) {
        // do something?
    }
}
```

This is what I have.

Shortly after this.wait() is called, I get an error down in the bowels of ThreadPoolExecuter.class.

```
Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #2 exiting due to uncaught exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I'm not quite sure what is going on here.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try putting another catch block after the one for InterruptedException but have it catch Exception and then use printStackTrace to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: If this is a long running task, then maybe you should be using a Service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is going to kill your battery.  Secondly, if you really, really want to do this, you should use a `Service` rather than an `AsyncTask`.  The latter is only supposed to be used for short lived, one-time uses, not for continuous background polling.

Comment: How would I make the Service sleep?

Comment: @Andrew you could use [`Handler#postdelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) on a `Runnable`

Comment: I'm a little confused about one thing.  postDelayed takes a Runnable (with my web service code) and a long (time in milliseconds) that is the time from now at which the Runnable should be executed.  My issue is, I want this to happen indefinitely, X amount of times, until I stop the Service.

Comment: @Andrew so the last thing that your runnable will do after it has finished its work is to `removeCallbacks()` then `postDelayed()` on itself.  Have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302060/self-updating-every-10-seconds-widget-handler-postdelayed-problem)

Comment: Though I do have to ask, why is using a Runnable & Handler less strenuous on the battery when done in a Service, as opposed to a Thread or AsyncTask?

Comment: It's the fact that you are performing a poll every 15 seconds that will kill your battery, whether it's done with an `AsyncTask` or a `Service`.  However if it is functionality that you need for your app then the best way to do it is with a `Service`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `Thread.sleep(15000)` instead? Or are you making use of the `notify` semantics?

Also, is there a "caused by ..." entry in logcat as well?